# Universal Analytics - firing in GTM but not firing in console

Tags: javascript, console, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

My **Universal Analytics tag** is set to fire **on all pages** through GTM - and for all but two pages is firing successfully into GA.

However on two pages of the website (form pages built in house) it shows **the tag as firing in GTM debugger but not in Tag Assistant or on the console *except* in Internet Explorer.**

I have other tags implemented in this way that are firing (classic GA & piwik) - it's just Universal that isn't passing back any information.

Has anyone seen this happening before? Any ideas on how to fix it?

If I've left any needed info out, do let me know. Thanks for any help!

Cheers,

Rosie

Answer (score 0):

You should deactivate **classic GA**. Universal is the replacement of classic version.

Comment: Hi Andrea - thanks for your response. We are running classic and universal in parallel until we are confident that Universal is receiving data correctly - which at the moment it isn't.

Comment: Classic and Universal are built to run along side each other with out interfering with each others performance aren't they?

Comment: All our other pages are receiving them both without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish the GTM container?
The GTM debugger only tests/debugs your tags and you have to actually publish the container first to start seeing data.

Comment: Hi ckorski - thanks for your message. Yes the container has been published - these tags were both implemented over a month ago and other tags have been implemented since.